# Is there a way to generate Rails fixtures from an existing set of models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, bdd, fixtures

I have a Rails 2.x app with no tests. I can write out the tests manually, but is there a way to generate fixtures automatically? It would be nice to not have to type all that out by hand.

I could run script/generate again for all the models, but everything already exists and if I understand generators correctly, I'd still have to type in all the attributes.

I thought about running the Rails console and doing for example...

```
>> y VendorUser.all.rand
```

That would give me some YAML with all the attributes, but they'd be out of order and it's still pretty time-consuming.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rake task to generate fixtures.

```
desc "extracting data for fixtures"
task :extract_fixtures => :environment do
  sql  = "SELECT * FROM %s"
  skip_tables = ["schema_info","schema_migrations"]
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - skip_tables).each do |table_name|
    i = "000"
    File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/test/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml", 'w' ) do |file|
      data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name)
      file.write data.inject({}) { |hash, record|
        hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
        hash
      }.to_yaml
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I knew someone would say "don't use fixtures." I just knew it! I can't deal with factories. The last time I tried to use them I spent hours on here trying to sort out weird problems and never arrived at a solution. Fixtures are like HTML tables: morally and philosophically wrong, but 100% reliable. Thanks. Your solution looks good.

Comment: @Ethan There's always a compromise between the two, IMO. They're not mutually exclusive. Ideally I'd write my project so it doesn't depend on specific rows, but every once in a while a fixture might be the only way. Especially on legacy projects.